# How to do Google App script firestore connection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an addon for gmail and the data I need is in the firestore. Can they help me connect firestore with Google app script

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use this library is to create a Google Service Account for your application and give it read/write access to your datastore. Giving a service account access to your datastore is like giving access to a user's account, but this account is strictly used by your script, not by a person.

If you don't already have a Firestore project you want to use, create one at the Firebase admin console.

To make a service account,

1. Open the Google Service Accounts page by clicking here.
2. Select your Firestore project, and then click "Create Service
   Account."
3. For your service account's role, choose Datastore > Cloud Datastore
   Owner.
4. Check the "Furnish a new private key" box and select JSON as your
   key type.
5. When you press "Create," your browser will download a .json file
   with your private key (private_key), service account email
   (client_email), and project ID (project_id). Copy these values into
   your Google Apps Script — you'll need them to authenticate with
   Firestore.
6. [Bonus] It is considered best practice to make use of the [Properties
   Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to
   store this sensitive information.

For more information on this Please refer this [link](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript).